# Procedure cannot be executed because fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE P_raise
AS
  v_salary     NUMBER;
  v_first_name VARCHAR2(20);
  v_min_salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT first_name,
    salary
  INTO v_first_name,
    v_salary
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary =
    (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employees
    );
  dbms_output.put_line(v_first_name||' has a minimum salary of '||v_salary);
  SELECT MIN(salary) INTO v_min_salary FROM employees;
  IF v_salary = v_min_salary THEN
    UPDATE employees SET salary = salary*1.15 WHERE salary=v_min_salary;
    dbms_output.Put_line(v_first_name||' has an increase of 15% in his salary ');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This messy code is used to find the min(salary) and then give it a raise. 
There are two minimum salary records with the same value. How do I rework my code to by pass the error?

Thanks

Comment: If there's a tie, which employee should get the raise? Without knowing that, there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: @mat Is there a way to give both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SELECT INTO` if the statement doesn't return exactly one row. Here you could use a loop, for instance with an implicit cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_raise AS
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT first_name, salary, ROWID
                INTO v_first_name, v_salary
                FROM employees
               WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employees)
                 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT) LOOP

      dbms_output.put_line(cc.first_name || ' has a minimum salary of ' 
                           || cc.salary);
      UPDATE employees SET salary = salary * 1.15 WHERE ROWID = cc.rowid;
      dbms_output.Put_line(cc.first_name 
                           || ' has an increase of 15% in his salary');

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Or use a straight update (which would be more efficient in general, although you won't have the details of which row got updated):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_raise AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE employees 
      SET salary = salary * 1.15 
    WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employees);
   dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT 
                        || ' employees had their salary increased by 15%');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you enlighten me what does the FOR UPDATE NOWAIT do in here?

Comment: Sure, [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55370) will lock the row so that no other session can modifies the rows returned by the select. It's mostly a good practice to lock the rows you are going to change. It removes the problem of the lost update (another session updates the same record between the select and the update). The `NOWAIT` makes sure that the procedure returns immediately if the row is locked, preventing indefinite waiting and deadlocks at the same time.